# Differences in Active Directory with and without Kerberos?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, kerberos

I have a web application (ASP.NET/C#) that our clients' employees use, and one of the authentication methods we support is an external Active Directory via LDAP.

I recently had a request to support Kerberos with AD.

What does this entail from a development perspective?  I know the basics of Kerberos in the Unix world, but not sure how it fits in with AD/LDAP

Currently, I use standard LDAP to bind with a service account to find the user, then bind as that user with their provided credentials to verify the login.

What is needed differently to support Kerberos?  My Google-fu is failing me.

To make it clear, the application server is not in the same domain as the AD server.

**EDIT:**

Is it even possible to do Kerberos authentication over an internet connection?

Comment: you should still be able to validate user credentials if they sit on 2 different domains  you want to look at the following `PrincipalContext`, 'UserPrincipal', 'GroupPrincipal if necessary', and `ValidateCredentials` which is probably the one you want the most

Comment: I think you've pointed me on the right track.  If you could submit this as an answer, I'll probably accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greg here is what you would need to look at.. if you need help with any code samples let me know.. I currently work in `Active Directory` Group and have 8+ yrs experience coding in C# for `AD and LDAP`

`you should still be able to validate user credentials if they sit on 2 different domains you want to look at the following PrincipalContext, 'UserPrincipal', 'GroupPrincipal if necessary', and ValidateCredentials which is probably the one you want the most`

Answer (score 0):

Kerberos has been standard in Windows for more than 13 years (since Windows 2000). All you need t do is enable Windows Auth with SPNEGO/Kerberos in your IIS. If you have a fat client, you can use SSPI to obtain a security context and read the currently logged in Kerberos UPN from. I have answered that kind of question already several times on SO. Please search.

Comment: Oh, and this also requires that the Client and the Server support SPNEGO/Kerberos. So if your only servers are IIS and your only clients use IE, then go for Otherwise, you should test the other clients to be used.

Comment: Not necessarily, Firefox and Chrome work too. But your clients and servers must run under a domain account. IIS/IE work for sure.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  I said it's not on the same domain.  It's not even in the same network.  I can't enable Windows auth in my application, as this isn't the only authentication method we support (we also do CAS (with and without SAML), Shibboleth, Banner, and a few others).

Maybe I'm just not asking the question correctly.  I'll edit it.

Comment: Do you have a cross-realm trust? If so, it should work as long as all DNS entries are alright.